# GitHub: How can I close the two issues with commit message?

Tags: github

I try

```
git commit -m "example of coding - close #1 close #2" 
git push origin develop
```

but it only close #1 issue. How can I close two or more issues with commit message?

Comment: Which issue tracker? Git doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: Assuming it's GitHub, see https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords#closing-multiple-issues. I'd expect "This closes #1 and closes #2" to work. You might want to use multiple lines in the commit message though.

Comment: Direct link to GitHub Docs: [Linking a pull request to an issue - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can use any of these keywords to close an issue via commit message:

```
close, closes, closed, fix, fixes, fixed, resolve, resolves, resolved
```

The message MUST contain a string matching the following pattern: `KEYWORD #ISSUE`. For example: `close #1`.

> How can I close two or more issues with commit message?

You can use comma separated list in the commit message for it.

See this [link](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/How-to-Close-Reference-issues-and-pull-request) for more information.

> It is also possible to close several issues in the same commit: just repeat several time the pattern to close issues. For example, the following commit message: add new quick sort algorithm, fixes #4, resolve #6, closed #12 would close, the issues 4, 6 & 12 of the project on which the commit would occur.

You can try:

```
git commit -m "closes #1, closes #2, closes #3; YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE"
```

**EDIT:**

Adding a link from [docs.github.com](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-issues/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue).

> You can link a pull request to an issue by using a supported keyword
> in the pull request's description or in a commit message (please note
> that the pull request must be on the default branch).

> close, closes, closed, fix, fixes, fixed, resolve, resolves  resolved

[image]

Comment: Note that it is not mandatory to start the commit message with the Github actions. It can be `YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE, fixes #4, resolve #6, closed #12` as explained in the pointed out Github documentation.

Comment: Also, FWIW the comma is not necessary either, so a commit message containing `fixes #4 and closes #6` also works.

Answer (score 37):

```
git commit -m "Closes #1, closes #2, closes #3; rest of commit message."
```

Comment: Sometimes short answers are the best.

Answer (score 8):

Please see the article  [closing-multiple-issues](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords#closing-multiple-issues) from github.

> To close multiple issues, preface each issue reference with one of the
>   above keywords. You must use the keyword before each issue you
>   reference for the keyword to work.
>
> **For example, This closes #34, closes #23, and closes
>   example_user/example_repo#42** would close issues #34 and #23 in the
>   same repository, and issue #42 in the "example_user/example_repo"
>   repository.

An example is:

```
git commit -m "closes #1, closes #2, closes #3; remaining commit message"
```

Comment: Useful article link.