# Git : pushing (Close issue #X ) message dosent close the issue

Tags: github, gitlab

When I push a commit with ( close issue #X) or (fixes issue #X) message.
The issue doesn't close but in the issue history, it appears that the issue was mentioned in a commit.

What am i doing wrong here? do i have to enable anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub: How can I close the two issues with commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027222/github-how-can-i-close-the-two-issues-with-commit-message)

Comment: What about not putting "issue" in between the word "close" and the ticket number? So instead of `close issue #X` use `close #X`?

Comment: Git is not relevant here, but GitHub and GitLab are. These are different systems so pick *one* (not both!).

Comment: @evolutionbox nope that didn't work, still the same issue

Comment: https://github.blog/2013-01-22-closing-issues-via-commit-messages/ - are these commits in your default branch (main/master)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope, the are on different branch.
Apparently there is no solution for that, unless i change my default branch

Comment: I think it's a design decision. _"Now when you enter “Fixes #33” in a commit message, issue 33
will only be closed once the commit is merged into your
**default** branch"_.